# Can the two same current monitoring ICs give different results?

Tags: current-measurement, gain

Have trouble testing of 30 pieces INA250A4PWR circuits like below. Produced as PCBA.

[image]

According to test results 21 out of 30 have mainly 1.98 V/A gain ratio.

But, 9 out of 30 have mainly 1.55 V/A gain ratio.

Question is, is it an ordinary situation if not what am i missing?

These are the gerber views:

Top:

[image]

Bottom:
[image]

This is what the PCB looks like:
[image]

I'll send you detailed test results when possible.

Edit: 25.03.2020

The supply current is DC. For a quick test that can reveal the problem, we chose two subjects to represent the perfect circuits(Sample 1 and sample 2) and two subjects to represent the circuits that we thought were defective(Sample 3 and sample 4).

This is the test result of four INA250A4:

[image]
Note: The supply current is DC.

And these are the test subjects:
[image]

Comment: Yes, no two things mass produced are identical...

Comment: @SolarMike a 22% variance is way outside of what the datasheet promises, though. AFAICS from this post, the input is within spec, and the datasheet is promising gain within less than 1% of nominal.

Comment: Is the lowered gain consistent over multiple measurements at various different inputs or have you only tested a single input point.

Comment: Yes, they are consistent over multiple measurements,1 Amps to 6 Amps gain ratio remains constant.

Comment: Are you using the same oscilloscope and the same probe, settings, etc to measure it?

Comment: I using the same oscilloscope and the same probe

Comment: @Lenel you said you have bought those products from China. Could the IC manufacturer have sold those ICs (the ones that outside the spec limits) to China? Just asking.

Comment: Might be worth checking if there are dodgy solder joints on the inputs/outputs that might be causing an additional voltage drop.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing that catches my eye is the gain/frequency plot ([figure 16](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina250.pdf)), are you measuring something near/above 10kHz?  They are only spec'ing "typical" gain, but all the graphs regarding gain have <1% effects.

Comment: We ordered these products(INA250A4) from china. So, I do not know if these products are original or not. Seller said original. If we think these are clone, could the error be caused by this?